# Show Ionic loading till data loaded

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm working on an app using Ionic framework in which I want to show loading spinning wheel till data is completely loaded from an API

Controller.js

```
.controller('PrayersCtrl', function($scope,Prayers,$ionicLoading,$timeout) {
                $ionicLoading.show({
                content: 'Loading',
                animation: 'fade-in',
                showBackdrop: true,
                maxWidth: 200,
                showDelay: 0
              });

        $scope.prayers = Prayers.query();
        $ionicLoading.hide();

    })
```

and Services.js

```
angular.module('starter.services', [])

.factory('Prayers', function($resource) {
    return $resource(base_url+'/wp/v2/posts');
});
```

in this case, Spinning wheel doesn't even show, (I mean it is so fast that it display and disappear in ms). than it take time to load data, meanwhile it displays blank page until data is loaded. I want to show spinning wheel till data is loaded in the page.

### Edited

I also tried timeout in controller.js

```
.controller('PrayersCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams,Prayers,$ionicLoading,$timeout) {
      $ionicLoading.show({
        content: 'Loading',
        animation: 'fade-in',
        showBackdrop: true,
        maxWidth: 200,
        showDelay: 0
      });
      $timeout(function () {
        $ionicLoading.hide();
        $scope.prayers = Prayers.query();
      }, 2000);
    })
```

But in this case, spinning wheel disappears after 2000 ms as shown in code;
I want to spinning code till data completed loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in controller.js, I added a $promise after query and some changes to display message in case of Network error

```
.controller('PrayersCtrl', function($scope,Prayers,$ionicLoading,$timeout) {
                $ionicLoading.show({
                content: 'Loading',
                animation: 'fade-in',
                showBackdrop: true,
                maxWidth: 200,
                showDelay: 0
              });

        $scope.prayers = Prayers.query().$promise.then(function(result){
         console.log(result);
         $scope.prayers=result;
         $ionicLoading.hide();
        }, function(error){
         console.log(error);
          $ionicLoading.hide();
          $ionicLoading.show({
            template: 'Network Error',
            scope: $scope
          });
          $timeout(function() {
             $ionicLoading.hide();
          }, 2000);
        })
    })
```

and make services back to its original form

```
angular.module('starter.services', [])

    .factory('Prayers', function($resource) {
        return $resource(base_url+'/wp/v2/posts');
    });
```

Comment: This was just what I was looking for. I had to tweek the above a little to get it to work for me. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Muhammad, I had to tweek your answer a little to get it to work for me. Here's my controller.

```
.controller('PrayersCtrl', function($scope, $ionicLoading, Prayers, $timeout) {
  $ionicLoading.show({
    template: '<ion-spinner icon="spiral" class="spinner-positive"></ion-spinner> <br>Loading...',
    noBackdrop: true,
    animation: 'fade-in'
  });
  Prayers.query().$promise.then(function(result){
    $scope.prayers = result;
    $ionicLoading.hide();
  }, function(error) {
    // error handling here
    $ionicLoading.hide();
    $ionicLoading.show({
      template: "unable to connect",
      noBackdrop: true
    });
    $timeout(function() {
       $ionicLoading.hide();
    }, 2000);
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this solution

```
.controller('PrayersCtrl', function($scope,Prayers,$ionicLoading,$timeout) {
                $ionicLoading.show({
                content: 'Loading',
                animation: 'fade-in',
                showBackdrop: true,
                maxWidth: 200,
                showDelay: 0
              });

        $scope.prayers = Prayers.query().then(function(result){
         console.log(result);
         $ionicLoading.hide();
        }, function(error){
         console.log(error);
          $ionicLoading.hide();
        })          
    })
```

In your factory edit the code as

```
angular.module('starter.services', [])

.factory('Prayers', function($resource, $q) {
  var self = this;
  self.query = function(){
  var defer = $q.defer();
   $resource(base_url+'/wp/v2/posts').then(function(result){
   console.log(result);
   defer.resolve("success");
   }, function(error){
   console.log(error);
   defer.reject("error");
  })
   return defer.promise;
  }
  return self;


});
```

Comment: it keeps on spinning with no data
with an error "Prayers.query(...).then is not a function"

Comment: It will hide when you get the data as successful or error

Comment: "Prayers.query(...).then is not a function" 
error on console when in inspected it

Comment: ok can you post your factory code... so that i will try and let you know

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107701/discussion-between-muhammad-faisal-iqbal-and-anil-kumar).

Comment: inject $q as dependency.... $q will return all the promises when it is done whether it is success or as an error

Comment: I made some changes and it did the job
thanks for pointing me towards right direction